# Syntactic representation of option parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 or TypeScript, is there a way to inline denote in your function header which of the parameter's are optional, just for the sake of readability? Maybe something like this:

```
function add(requiredNumber, required Number [, optionalNumber])
```

I looked in the documentation and there doesn't seem to be, but I figured I would ask.

Comment: `function add(requiredNumber1, requiredNumber2 /*, optionalNumber*/)` if you are looking to not make it a formal parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no headers in JavaScript. You can't declare a function in one place and implement it somewhere else, but...

In ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6) you can use default values like this:

```
function add(requiredNumber, optionalNumber = 1) {}
```

Then if you call `add(100)` the effect would be as if you called `add(100, 1)`.

That should provide a good hint to anyone reading this that the 2nd parameter is optional.

Other than that, you can (and should) always use a descriptive comment above your functions that describe what they do and what parameters they accept / expect.